# Print Array of arrays to string using join and map

Tags: python

Assuming I have

```
a = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

I want to, using a oneliner with `join` and `map`, print it as :

```
0 1
0 2
```

The closest I got is :

```py
print("\n".join(map("".join, map(str, a))))
```

which gives :

```
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
```

Comment: What is variable "res"?

Comment: It meant to be "a", typo

Comment: Try `'\n'.join(map(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x)), a))`

Comment: @QuarticCat `map(lambda)` is ugly. Use a comprehension instead. `'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in a)`

Comment: @wjandrea What would be the equivalent without using "for x in a" ?

Comment: @adaba Using `map(lambda)`, which is ugly. Is there a reason you want to avoid a comprehension?

Comment: can't you just do a simple: `for i in a: print (*i)`

Comment: @wjandrea Because OP asks for `join` and `map`s. If comprehension is allowed, you can write `'\n'.join(' '.join(str(e) for e in l) for l in a)`

Comment: @QuarticCat `map(str)` is fine. It's specifically `map(lambda)` that's ugly, because a comprehension is easier to read, less complicated, and shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are one level of iteration away:

```
In []:
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, b)) for b in a))

Out[]:
0 1
0 2
```

Or:

```
In []:
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, map(lambda b: map(str, b), a))))

Out[]:
0 1
0 2
```

Or if you really don't want to use lambda, then you can use `functools.partial` but now it is getting really ugly:

```
import functools as ft

In []:
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, map(ft.partial(map, str), a))))

Out[]:
0 1
0 2
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent without using "for b in a" ?

Comment: You can `map()` but you need a `lambda`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map` and `lambda`:

```
print("\n".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(map(str, x)), a)))
0 1
0 2
```

Edit: Just saw the comment with the same method, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more cleanly by using a for-loop with `print` instead of a one-liner with `map` and `join`:

```
for x in a:
    print(*x)
```

`print` automatically converts its arguments to string, joins them on spaces, and adds a trailing newline.